# GAMS Tag (Different from GAM)

Tags: support, tags

There is a need for a GAMS tag, where GAMS is an optimization modeling language similar to AMPL (which already has a tag). See http://www.gams.com/, my now old request for a tag at [Best practice for cross-platform file system manipulations in GAMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666921/best-practice-for-cross-platform-file-system-manipulations-in-gams), the conversation in the comments below https://stackoverflow.com/a/11142980/1470262, and doing a search for 'GAMS' in StackOverflow will turn up more questions that could use a GAMS tag.

Also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11142980/1470262, you will see that someone attempted to make the tag, but was rejected because there is already a tag for 'gam', but that is something different.

Thank you!

Comment: Blocked automatically by the system, not by reviewers.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (@Will can correct me if I'm wrong), mods can override the prohibition on tags that only differ by an "s".

Comment: Does it also reject things like "gams-language"?

Comment: I did not try that. It generally seems less elegant, but would be better than nothing. I do not have enough reputation to create it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag `gams-math` created. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gams-math/info

Comment: Thank you! And double-thanks for already tagging the questions linked to above!